# Terraform Data Source to get data lake gen2 id

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

Is there a data source to get "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.example.name" or "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.example.id"

```
resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_path" "example" {
  path               = "example"
  filesystem_name    = azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.example.name
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
  resource           = "directory"
}
```

Comment: Hey @! had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `data` source for `azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_path` as already mentioned. If there was a data source, the name attribute would not be that useful since you would generally require the name in advance to reference the resource.

The id, however, is a domain name which can be interpolated manually if you already know the name of the filesystem and the storage account to which it belongs:

```
https://${storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/${filesystem_name}
```

Answer (score -1):

No there is no data source for `azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem`. You need to use `resource` for `azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem`.Because `azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_path` is manage by  File System within an Azure Storage Account.

**Data lake filesystem** - this module creates a data lake filesystem, and enables the deployment service principal to manage that filesystem. It also sets default permissions for paths and the root filesystem, so that resources won't get recreated again. The Terraform module can be found [***here***](https://github.com/recognizegroup/terraform/tree/develop/modules/data_lake_filesystem).